# Adjust font size in `Grid`

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts, fonts

I have a simple table given by

```
Grid[MapThread[
 Prepend, {Prepend[
  Table[x + m, {m, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 5}], 
  {"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
 "5"}], {"", "m=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}}], 
Frame -> {{True}, {True}}]
```

I want to use `FontSize` to adjust the font. Where do I add this option to the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Grid[MapThread[Prepend, {Prepend[
    Table[x + m, {m, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 5}], {"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}], 
    {"", "m=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}}], 
 Frame -> {{True}, {True}}, 
 BaseStyle -> 24]
```

[image]

Use `BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 24, FontSlant -> Italic}` to get

[image]

You can also wrap each element of the table with `Style` to style the elements as desired:

```
Grid[Map[Style[#, 24, Italic, Red] &, #, {-1}] &@
 MapThread[Prepend, {Prepend[
     Table[x + m, {m, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 5}], {"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}], 
    {"", "m=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}}], 
 Frame -> {{True}, {True}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How do I add that to the ta blue instruction set? I only want this one table changed.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward, not sure I  understand. If you want to make changes only  in the first argument of `Grid` to get the desired effect, please see the update.

Comment: Got it now. Appreciated.